# Which memory does the Tensorflow programs use to store the data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, ram

I think following situation.

1. make a ML model with Tensorflow with GPU for image classification problem
2. for loading the images, use pillow and for pre-processing, use numpy
3. the ML model get the input data in the tf.placeholder

I understand that tensorflow-gpu use RAM on GPUs if possible to store the parameters as default. But for the input data before passing to tf.placeholder, which RAM is it stored in, RAM for CPU or it for GPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition a [placeholder](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder) has no data until fed. Making many assumptions here, unless you copy your data to GPU memory in its entirety via [tf.constant()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant) which can be done if your data set will fit within the available GPU memory, the data exists in CPU/system memory and needs to be copied to GPU memory.

Based on what you describe in steps 1 and 2, it would look something like the naive implementation/lack of pipelining as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets#pipelining).[image]

> However, in a naive synchronous implementation, while the CPU is preparing the data, the accelerator is sitting idle. Conversely, while the accelerator is training the model, the CPU is sitting idle. The training step time is thus the sum of both CPU pre-processing time and the accelerator training time.

Prior to the training steps, your data exists in CPU/system memory.

Comment: Thanks, so if I have all data as list or numpy array and fed some data as a batch to placeholder using generator, the whole data are not allocated in CPU memory, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the data exists in CPU memory until it is copied to GPU memory. At which point whatever data that has been copied whether it be a subset/batch or the entire data set, will exist in both CPU and GPU memory.